# php search trying to get property of non object

Tags: php

I am working on a project to search for prices of books based on ISBN numbers. Most of the time it works however every once and a while I receive trying to get property of non object. It happens on line 16 (I can't get it to break right now or I would copy paste the exact message).

```
01: <?php
02: 
03: function search($query){
04: 
05:     $Amazon = "http://www.amazon.com/dp/".$query;
06:     $url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=amazon%20".$query."%20buy%20new.%20price";
07: 
08: $body = file_get_contents($url);
09: if (is_null(json_decode($body)))
10: {
11: $myArray = "a";
12: }
13: else
14: {
15: $json = json_decode($body);
16: $stuff = $json->responseData->results[0]->content;
17: 
18: 
19:     $myArray = str_split($stuff);
20:     }
21: 
22: $out = '$';
23: 
24: for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($myArray) - 1; $i++)
25: {
26:     if ($myArray[$i] == '$')
27:     {
28:         while($myArray[$i] != '.')
29:         {
30:             $out = $out.$myArray[$i+1];
31:             $i++;
32:         }
33:         $out = $out.$myArray[$i+1].$myArray[$i+2];
34:         break;
35:     }
36: }
37: if ($out == '$')
38: {
39:     $out = "Amazon does not sell this book";
40:     $amazon1=$out;
41:     //print_r($out);
42:     echo "<br>";
43: }
44: else
45: { 
46: 
47:     $amazon1 ="Buy new from "."<a href=$Amazon>Amazon</a>"." for ".$out;
48:     echo "<br>";
49: 
50: }
```

this is not the entire code just the beginning. where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Ad more info, like error description and your input. I consider your error is in line "$stuff = $json->responseData->results[0]->content;" . so most probably your $body could be non json formatted or simply empty.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is looking for an object and not getting one, probably here

```
    $stuff = $json->responseData->results[0]->content;
```

You should probably handle this by checking if it is an object first, using

```
 if(is_object ( $json )){
   //do stuff
}
```